# Is it feasible (In terms of gas cost) to call a function of deployed contract from other smart contract on mainnet (ethereum)?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I need to call the transfer function of my deployed ERC20 token in a new contract which needs to be deployed on mainnet. I want to know would it be feasible or it will be requiring a lot of gas and in turns high transaction charges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's feasible - it's the way contracts interact with eachother. In general, we use an interface in the calling contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

// Define an interface to the contract you want to call. Only need function signatures

interface YourErc20Contract {
        function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external;
    }

contract CallingContract {
    
    address your_erc20_address = 0x.....  // called contract address here
    address recipient = 0x....  // arguments for the function call
    uint amount = 2  


    // Call the function on the other contract using the interface
    function remoteCall(address recipient, uint amount) public {
        YourErc20Contract(your_erc20_address).transfer(recipient, amount)
        }
    }
```